# How to plot graphics with the colors of each pixel in the image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, graph

I'm working on image color recognition, so I'm converting the RGB image to Lab because it's the closest color space to human vision. After that, I get each one of the Lab's 3 channels and I want to plot in the 3D graphic the color variations that I identified in the converted image. How do I plot the graphic with the colors of the image?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load an image that contains all possible colors.
request = urllib.urlopen('IMD021.png')
image_array = np.asarray(bytearray(request.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image_array, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)

lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l_channel,a_channel,b_channel = cv2.split(lab_image)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(l_channel, a_channel, b_channel, marker='o',  facecolors=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).reshape(-1,3)/255.)

ax.set_xlabel('L')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
ax.set_zlabel('B')
fig.add_axes(ax)
#plt.savefig('plot-15.png')
plt.show()
```

Exit:
[image]

Comment: So that *is* plotting it correctly---presumably all you want is the marker color to correspond to the color that it's position represents. Is that correct? If so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399248/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-with-marker-color-corresponding-to-rgb-values)

Comment: yes, but in the case of the link that sent me it does with random colors, I want to load with the colors of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how to get the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29399590/1628638) Alexander suggested to work in your case:

```python
# only change to question's code is the ax.scatter() line:
ax.scatter(l_channel, a_channel, b_channel, marker='o',
  facecolors=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).reshape(-1,3)/255.)
```

Note: The `facecolors` argument requires RGB, not OpenCV's BGR, and is picky about the shape and type of the color data, hence the reshape and division.

Here the result when the code is applied to [this image](https://www.warwickshire-butterflies.org.uk/species/butterflies/Common%20Blue-small.jpg):[image]

Comment: Simple and to the point. Also, what a nice photo to use to showcase this! It's so uniform! Something I like to do here as well is map the opacity and size of the markers to the quantity of pixels with that value---giving a little dimension to the inner distribution via the opacity and seeing the density of color via size. Not that this answer needs to have that addition, but it is a nice thought for anyone implementing for a presentation or something.

Comment: @Alexander I changed the code according to your suggestion, I updated the question, and I am using the image above to plot the graph. Even so the graph is plotted all in blue color.

Comment: @CarlosDiego, I got [this colored plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xaS.png) running your updated code for the image in your question.

Comment: Really? Weird, it's blushing here in blue. Do you have any idea what that might be? the code is identical, only the blue color is shown

Comment: My only guess is that maybe the old code (or code that still contains `c='b'`) is run by accident when you generate the plot.  But I assume you checked for that.

Comment: @UlrichStern Did you ever see any difference in the code?

Comment: I had run revision 2 of your code ("updated code") before.  I just ran revision 3 of your code and got the correctly colored plot again.  My matplotlib version is 2.1.2.  And out-commenting your `fig.add_axes(ax)` gets rid of a MatplotlibDeprecationWarning for me.

Comment: @UlrichStern I'm trying to run this code now and it gives me error AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen' But weeks ago it worked perfectly.

Comment: @CarlosDiego, I assume you searched for your error message and tried some of the suggestions?  E.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969726/1628638) is the first Google result for me and looks like it's worth a try.

Comment: @UlrichStern you can help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Comment: @CarlosDiego, sorry, currently too busy.