# how to plot 3d hstogram with different plots for Red green and blue values as shown in the image

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Plotting the histograms 
is there a way to 3D plot the Red green blue values histogram using python.

[image: I want this type of histogram]

Comment: possible related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781845/how-to-plot-3d-graphics-with-the-values-of-each-pixel-of-the-image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995610/how-to-make-a-4d-plot-with-matplotlib-using-arbitrary-data

Comment: thank you, but it's not the same question